# Best way to find HSV values

Tags: opencv, hsv

I am going to apply a HSV threshold to the image below in order to extract the tennis ball. But I could not figure out the best way to find the correct HSV values of the ball. Which method/software do you suggest to me? (I am using Ubuntu) Also according to your experiences which min/max values do you prefer to me? (±10? ±5?)

Regards

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) to get needed color. The tool is called [Color Picker](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-color-picker.html). It also shows HSV values. Here's screenshot of your image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered to use [`Hough Circle`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) ?

I think in this case it would be much more indicted, because the colors in your image aren't so clear

Comment: Yeah, I am going to apply it after applying a color thresholding. Because there may be other balls with different colors and I want to be able to discard them.